# Quartz error after upgrading spring to 5.3.27 and quartz-scheduler 2.3.1

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, quartz, spring-framework-beans

After upgrading spring from 5.1.20 to 5.3.27 and quartz-scheduler from 2.2.1 to 2.3.1 I got an error saying:

"org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobManager' defined in URL [jar:file:DefaultJobManager.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-standard-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Non-ManagedTX DataSource name not set!  If your 'org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource' is XA, then set 'org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource' to a non-XA datasource (for the same DB).  Otherwise, you can set them to be the same."

"Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-standard-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Non-ManagedTX DataSource name not set!  If your 'org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource' is XA, then set 'org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource' to a non-XA datasource (for the same DB).  Otherwise, you can set them to be the same.
"

"Caused by: org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Non-ManagedTX DataSource name not set!  If your 'org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource' is XA, then set 'org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource' to a non-XA datasource (for the same DB).  Otherwise, you can set them to be the same."

I don't know the reason of this problem as I found that the new version of quartz is compatible with spring 5.3.27

Answer (score 0):

I removed these two lines from the quartz configuration and it fixed the issue:

```
<entry key="org.quartz.jobStore.class" value="org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT"/>

<entry key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass" value="${quartz.jdbcdelegate}"/>
```